# Adjusting the pressure of the condenser and the evaporator

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, pressure, compressors, refrigeration

The picture below shows a refrigeration unit

[image]

I was reading the operation manual of this unit. It is written that the pressure of the condenser is controlled by the water flow rate. Reducing water flow rate will increase the pressure of the condenser.

On the other hand, the pressure of the evaporator is controlled by the refrigeration load or cooling capacity (Q dot L). Increasing Q dot L is acheived by adjusting the voltage of the electric heater. The pressure of the evaporator is increased by increasing Q dot L.

Can you explain to me how could reducing water flow rate cause the condenser pressure to increase ? And how could increasing the cooling capacity cause the pressure of the evaporator to increase ?